# Create a third pary library jar with JPA project

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, jar

First off, I am pretty new to this. I am working on a desktop application which uses hibernate and an embedded h2 database. I am trying to create this project with 'modules' so that we may easily update code as needed. Right now I am trying to create a separate project witch contains our entity definitions, named-queries, and persistence.xml file. I created a JPA project to do this. My question is, how do I export this jar in order to be able to replace it in the future when changes are made? I create a runnable jar which points the the main of the core application, which I am not sure about, and it will run. My problem is when I create the lib folder next to the runnable jar of the core application, my custom 3rd  party library containing our entity definition is not there? I am guessing this is because of how I pointed the library to the main of the core application, but as I said I have little experience with this so I am not sure. I cannot seem to find anything helpful out there but I know it must exist. If anyone knows what my issue is or where I should go to read about it, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is with how you package your app? Be aware that a JAR file cannot include other JAR files (at least they are not included in the classpath). Only WAR and EAR may contain another JAR files. If you want to include a JAR nested in another JAR, you must repackage them and merge into a big JAR file, not only put one into another.

Comment: Correct, this part I understand. Maybe I wasn't clear so let me try to explain a little better. When I go to export my project into the runnable jar, I have 3 choices for library handling: extract into the generated jar, package into the generated jar, or copy into a sub-folder next to the jar. The third choice is what I am after but my custom library with my entity definitions does not show here even though i have it as a jar included in my library for the core project.

Comment: How do you export your project? Do you press a button in your IDE, or is it a build command in maven or other build tool?

Comment: I use Eclipse to build. There is no build tool in place. I go to export-> jar file for the library and export->runnable jar for the main application with libraries in a sub-folder next to the runnable.

Comment: I see, building a project this way is pretty non-standard and eclipse-specific. I recommend to ide maven and some plugin to create runnable jar - you would support from more people. Using eclipse, I would review if projects are configured to be exported in build path settings.